# Is neutrino in superposition state else how does it knows when to change flavor?

Tags: neutrinos

Is the neutrino being in all 3 flavors at the same time until observed if not how does it know when to alter its mass and become another flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not have all three  flavors at the same time, it [oscillates between flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation).

A neutrino, because of lepton number conservation always starts with a fixed flavor, and then the probability of finding a specific flavor oscillates, let us take an electron neutrino from the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Three_neutrino_probabilities):

[image: electronneutrino oscillation]: [image: shortrange]

> Electron neutrino oscillations, long range. Here and in the following diagrams black means electron neutrino, blue means muon neutrino and red means tau neutrino

The neutrino  wave function squared "knows", given the initial conditions, it gives the probability distributions.

Comment: Thanks I must have got confused with probability is involved.